# Android - deleting items from ListView but not from Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

So I have a small problem, my code deletes ListView row from ListView but every time I kill the app and then reopen it the "deleted" rows populate the ListView again.

Here's the code for delete method in DatabaseHelper class:

```
 public void obrisiTrening(int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(DBKonstante.TABLE_NAME, DBKonstante.KEY_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
        db.close();
```

And here's what my code for deleting ListView row and record from database:

```
  rec_WorkoutItemsList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int i, long l) {


            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_delete);

            final TextView tvDialogDelete = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvDialogDelete);

            tvDialogDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    final DBPodatci infoData = dbPodatci.get(i);
                    dba = new DBHandler(MainActivity.this);
                    int position = dbPodatci.indexOf(infoData);
                    dbPodatci.remove(position);

                    DBPodatci podatki = new DBPodatci();
                    final int idToDelete = podatki.getItemId();

                    dba.obrisiTrening(idToDelete);
                    dba = new DBHandler(MainActivity.this);
                    dba.obrisiTrening(i);

                    rec_WorkoutItemsList.setAdapter(vjezbaAdapter);
                    vjezbaAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            });
            dialog.show();

            return false;
        }
    });
```

DB PODATCI

```
public class DBPodatci {
    public String odabraneVjezbe, recordDate;
    public int itemId;

    public String getOdabraneVjezbe() {
        return odabraneVjezbe;
    }

    public void setOdabraneVjezbe(String odabraneVjezbe) {
        this.odabraneVjezbe = odabraneVjezbe;
    }

    public String getRecordDate() {
        return recordDate;
    }

    public void setRecordDate(String recordDate) {

    this.recordDate = recordDate;
}

public int getItemId() {
    return itemId;
}

public void setItemId(int itemId) {
    this.itemId = itemId;
}
```

}

Comment: try to debug i think you are getting wrong id from your list

Comment: Post `DBPodatci ` this Class so that we can check what `podatki.getItemId()` this line returns

Comment: It's in the first post

Comment: `final DBPodatci infoData = dbPodatci.get(i);`. You have a random `i` variable. The value of `i` has noting to do with the position of the clicked item in the list. Try to determine the position first.

Comment: Implement an onItemClickListener which gives you the position of the clicked item.

Comment: See my updated code, I've forgot to mention that variable i was from onItemLongClickListener method

Comment: debug in db code and see if it is giving any exception or error.

Comment: try replace final int idToDelete = podatki.getItemId(); to int idToDelete = infoData.getItemId();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what this is trying to do.

```
dba.obrisiTrening(idToDelete);
dba = new DBHandler(MainActivity.this);
dba.obrisiTrening(i);
```

You only need this

```
   final TextView tvDialogDelete = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvDialogDelete);

    final DBHandler dba = new DBHandler(MainActivity.this);

        tvDialogDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final DBPodatci infoData = dbPodatci.get(i);
                final int idToDelete = infoData.getItemId();

                dbPodatci.remove(i);  
                dba.obrisiTrening(idToDelete);

                vjezbaAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                dialog.dismiss();
```

And note: you shouldnt be using an Arraylist & ArrayAdapter here... You are using a database, so CursorAdapter is what you want